# Sort Two Columns of Data into One and Keep Duplicates

Tags: excel, sorting, duplicates

I have two columns of dates. One list has quarterly reporting dates, one has annual reporting dates, so every year (except in strange situations) there is a quarterly date that matches an annual date. I would like to sort the two columns into one, like they do [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/29/merge-two-columns-into-one-list-in-excel/), except that I want to keep the duplicates.

So if

List 1

- 3.31.2010
- 6.30.2010
- 9.30.2010
- 12.31.2011

List 2

- 12.31.2011

Then the end result would be a list (column in excel) as follows

- 3.31.2010
- 6.30.2010
- 9.30.2010
- 12.31.2011
- 12.31.2011

The lists am dealing with are not easily sorted by hand like this example and I understand that a formula can be written successfully do this by doubling every fourth entry; however, I need a formula that can handle when the fiscal year changes and the annual dates stop following the every four quarters rule.

Comment: Why not just copy and paste one list under the other then sort it?

Comment: The end of the list is dynamic. I don't know where the end is going to be. It pulls data indefinitely so if these date columns are changed it ruins the purpose of automation.

Comment: Are they true dates or are they text that looks like dates?

Comment: True dates, I can convert need be

Comment: Then `=SMALL($A$1:$B$4,ROW(1:1))` in The first cell and drag down.  It will order them from smallest to largest combining the two ranges.

Comment: Wow! Brilliantly simple, thanks so much